# Connection error with Gunicorn / Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am learning nginx and configuring nginx.conf with gunicorn. I am running  gunicorn on port 8000 and nginx listening on port 80. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it gives an "Unable to connect" error.

Here is my nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;

}


http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

> I have supervisor config file:
>   here is my supervisor config file

```
[program:python-activate]
directory=<path of my directory>
command=/home/ashiyap/ianp3.sh gunicorn  proj.wsgi:application  -b 0.0.0.0:8000
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor.out.log
```

> Here is my nginx python conf file

```
server {
# the port your site will be served on
listen      80;
# the domain name it will serve for
server_name <ipaddress>;   # substitute by your FQDN and machine's IP address
charset     utf-8;
#Max upload size
client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

# Django media
location /media  {
   root /home/ashiyap/test/wp005_v02.00.00.d2_itr1/proj;      # your Django project's media files
   autoindex off;
 }

location /static {
   root /home/ashiyap/test/wp005_v02.00.00.d2_itr1/proj;      # your Django project's static file
   autoindex off;
}

# Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
location / {

    proxy_pass http://<ipaddress>:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your website config file from nginx and how you're starting gunicorn?

Comment: @GwynBleidD  I have updated my question. please see

Comment: Where's your python projects configuration file for Nginx? You've only given the basic config.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence.. added my nginx config file for pytho

Comment: I saw nginx  error logs , i am getting this error:     

2016/09/14 11:27:22 [error] 28591#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <ipaddress>, server: <ipaddress>, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://<ipaddress>:8000/", host: "<ipaddress>"

Comment: In your root location, are you proxying to a different server or to the same server? If you're running the app on the same server as Nginx, use `127.0.0.1` as your proxy IP and change your gunicorn to `... -b 127.0.0.1:8000` so that you're only targeting the loopback interface and not binding on all available IPs on port 8000

Comment: yes. but i want run my project on ip address.., After changing 127.0.0.1, getting same problem..:(

Comment: Your project will still be run from your ip address. But you shouldn't proxy to your IP address with that port. See this [Q&A](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/502-bad-gateway-ngnix-gunicorn) for some help. It should be working now, unless something else is wrong (perhaps a permission issue, but I doubt it)

Comment: thanks @KeenanLawrence

Comment: Did you manage to get it working @Ashiya?